# SVG pie chart pull text to top

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, z-index

I have a SVG pie chart that is being auto generated by code. I want to ensure the text always shows up, however it is getting overlapped by color fills in the pie chart. I've tried using render-order to fix this to no avail. What can I do to get the equivalent of z-index in a SVG?

Here is the example code. Copy/paste and you'll see the problem.

```
<svg width="180" height="180"><g transform="translate(90,90)"><g class="slice"><path fill="#D0D0D0" d="M-39.049536520580226,81.08719811121772A90,90 0 0,1 -87.74351209636413,20.026884056068305L0,0Z"></path><text transform="translate(-35.18241671106134,28.05704108364301)" text-anchor="middle" render-order="109">Black - 14%</text></g><g class="slice"><path fill="#CEECC6" d="M-87.74351209636413,20.026884056068305A90,90 0 0,1 -70.36483342212269,-56.114082167286L0,0Z"></path><text transform="translate(-40.871756048182064,-10.013442028034143)" text-anchor="middle" render-order="300">Green - 14%</text></g><g class="slice"><path fill="#FFA8A8" d="M-70.36483342212269,-56.114082167286A90,90 0 0,1 -1.6532185776602093e-14,-90L0,0Z"></path><text transform="translate(-19.524768260290124,-40.54359905560886)" text-anchor="middle" render-order="109">Red - 14%</text></g><g class="slice"><path fill="#FFE8A1" d="M5.510728592200698e-15,-90A90,90 0 1,1 -39.049536520580226,81.08719811121772L0,0Z"></path><text transform="translate(43.871756048182064,10.013442028034147)" text-anchor="middle" render-order="109">Yellow - 57%</text></g></g></svg>
```

Comment: please try to make fiddle,it will be easy to fix your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no z-index or render-order in SVG currently, although this is planned for the next version of the specification (SVG 2) which is currently being written by w3c. It uses painter's model i.e. whatever you put in the file last is drawn on top like a painter always paints on top of what's gone before.

If you want the text to be on top then you must add it to the SVG file after anything that it may overlap.

Comment: To add to Robert's comment:  you can create two groups in your SVG, one for pie pieces, the other for labels; make sure the labels come after the shapes.  Then use an [`each()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-each) function call within the selection in which you create the pie pieces to add  each label to the other group.